# jquery and selectors

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I want to have a click event on the body tag, but I have a div under the body tag which i dont want to have the click event on. I have tryed with this but that doesent seem to work correct:

```
$("body").not("#InnerDiv").click(function() {
    alert("Hejhej");
});
```

The html:

```
<body>
   <div id="1">1</div>
   <div id="2">2</div>
   <div id="InnerDiv">InnerDiv</div>
</body>
```

Comment: What happens when you do that? Does the click even still fire for InnerDiv, or does the click event not fire for anything?

Comment: I think this could use the tag "events"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click events bubble up. The default click handler on InnerDiv delegates to the click event of its parent.
You can override that event and ask it not to bubble up.

```
$("body").click(function() {
          alert("Hejhej");
      });
$("#InnerDiv").click(function(e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
      });
```

Comment: stopPropagation... that was what I was looking for, I couldn't find it in the documentation

Comment: yeah, jQuery's documentation on these methods was really hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    $("body").click(function() { alert("Hejhej"); });
    $('#InnerDiv').click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
```